# NULL values in ACCESS reports?

Tags: ms-access, report

I created a simple report that has 5 columns (CompanyName, Bought, Sold, Returned, Total)
This is what it looks like.

**CompanyName       Bought       Sold       Returned        Total**

With the exception of the Company Name, every value is a number. I created simple queries for Bought, Sold and Returned. For Total I used arithmetic in the main query (basically the sum of Bought, Sold, Returned (Returned is always negative)). The problem I came across is that for some companies, some of the columns (Bought,Sold,Returned) are NULL since ex: they don't have any RETURNED so when I run the report, it doesn't show me any value for TOTAL. Unless I have values in all three(BOUGHT SOLD and RETURNED) - nothing gets displayed in TOTAL. I don't want to display any zeros in the report itself because it would be too clustered, but is there a way for me to convert the NULL to 0 only when it does the calculation and but hide it from the report?

Comment: Seems like the [Nz Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Nz-Function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved!